# BasicHttpBinding equivalent CustomBinding using WCF Client and PHP WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf-security, ntlm, basichttpbinding

I was running my Visual Studio 2008 Unit Test C# with a WebService PHP using WCF and I received the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException:
>   The HTTP request is unauthorized with
>   client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header
>   received from the server was
>   'NTLM,Basic realm="(null)"'. ---> 
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized..

I am using Windows XP SP3 machine, unit test VS 2008 and WCF for connect to PHP WebService.

I have no control about PHP WebService. I cannot modify it (neither configuration security).

Here is my config file for the client that use the webservice PHP:

```
 <system.serviceModel>

    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="customTextMessageEncoding"
             type="COMPANY.IntegracionEasyVista.CustomTextEncoder.CustomTextMessageEncodingElement,COMPANY.IntegracionEasyVista.CustomTextEncoder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9744987c0853bf9e" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>

    </extensions>


        <bindings>

              <customBinding>
                    <binding name="ISO8859Binding">
                          <customTextMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10"
                                encoding="ISO-8859-1" />
                          <httpTransport />
                    </binding>
              </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
              <endpoint address="http://serverphp/webservice/SmoBridge.php"
                    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ISO8859Binding"
                    contract="ServiceEasyVista.WebServicePortType" name="EasyVistaSvcEndPoint" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Really, I use C# code:

```
var endpointAddress = Config.AppSettings.Settings[EasyVistaSvcEndPointAddress].Value;
var endpoint = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(endpointAddress);

var endpointBinding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding();
endpointBinding.Name = "ISO8859Binding";

var bindingElement = new  IntegracionEasyVista.CustomTextEncoder.CustomTextMessageBindingElement();

bindingElement.Encoding = "ISO-8859-1";
bindingElement.MessageVersion = System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10; // "Soap11WSAddressing10" 
endpointBinding.Elements.Add(bindingElement);

var transportBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
endpointBinding.Elements.Add(transportBinding);

ConfigurarBinding(endpointBinding);

var svcClient = new WebServicePortTypeClient(endpointBinding, endpoint);
return svcClient;
```

Update: tests

I add this line:

```
transportBinding.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
```

I get this error: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM,Basic realm="(null)"'

I add this line:

```
transportBinding.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
```

I get thiserror:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException:
>   El objeto de comunicación,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel,
>   no se puede usar para la comunicación
>   porque se encuentra en el estado
>   Faulted.
>
> //Server stack trace:  //   en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan
>   timeout)

I add this line:

```
 transportBinding.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm;
```

I get thiserror:

> /Exception =
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   Versión de mensaje no reconocida.
>
> //Server stack trace:  //   en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader)
>
> //   en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamedMessage..ctor(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders,
>   MessageVersion desiredVersion)
>
> //   en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(XmlDictionaryReader
>   envelopeReader, Int32
>   maxSizeOfHeaders, MessageVersion
>   version)
>
> //   en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(XmlReader
>   envelopeReader, Int32
>   maxSizeOfHeaders, MessageVersion
>   version)
>
> //   en
>   CustomTextEncoder.CustomTextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream
>   stream, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders, String
>   contentType) en
>   E:\TFS\pro\CustomTextEncoder\CustomTextMessageEncoder.cs:línea
>   66
>
> //   en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream
>   stream, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders)
>
> //   en
>   CustomTextEncoder.CustomTextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage
>   (ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager
>   bufferManager, String contentType) en
>   E:\TFS\pro\CustomTextEncoder\CustomTextMessageEncoder.cs:línea
>   60
>
> //   en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream
>   stream, BufferManager bufferManager,
>   Int32 maxBufferSize, String
>   contentType)
>
> //   en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadChunkedBufferedMessage(Stream
>   inputStream)

I think, the following is right configuration (if were basichttpbinding)

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
</security>
```

Web service of WCF in basichttpbinding might not be flexible enough. CustomBinding as the name describes that it alllows users design their own web service binding.

I need use **CustomBinding** and SecurityMode (like basichttpbinding): WCF BasicHttpBinding equivalent CustomBinding

I need Security Mode: TransportCredentialOnly, Basic, HTTP transport and  encoding="ISO-8859-1"

http://www.codemeit.com/security/wcf-basichttpbinding-equivalent-custombinding.html

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/6cefadf1-9939-4f3b-a502-2d79a30c7d3a

http://offroadcoder.com/2008/03/23/CallingYourNusoapPHPWebServiceFromWCF.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092(v=VS.90).aspx

I try again using this configuration, and I get the error:

```
svcPro.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MY USER";
svcPro.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "XXXX";
```

Config:

```
<customBinding>

<binding name="ISO8859Binding">
    <customTextMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10"        encoding="ISO-8859-1" />

    <!--<textMessageEncoding MessageVersion="Soap11" />-->
    <!--<httpTransport />-->
    <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" />

</binding>

</customBinding>
```

The error (InnerException is null):

> Error: Unrecognized message version
>
> Tipo:
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException
>   Mensaje: Versión de mensaje no
>   reconocida. StackTrace:  Server stack
>   trace:
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader)
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamedMessage..ctor(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders,
>   MessageVersion desiredVersion)
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(XmlDictionaryReader
>   envelopeReader, Int32
>   maxSizeOfHeaders, MessageVersion
>   version)
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(XmlReader
>   envelopeReader, Int32
>   maxSizeOfHeaders, MessageVersion
>   version)
>
> en
>   Reale.IntegracionEasyVista.CustomTextEncoder.CustomTextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream
>   stream, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders, String
>   contentType) en
>   E:\IntegracionEasyVista\CustomTextEncoder\CustomTextMessageEncoder.cs:línea
>   66
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream
>   stream, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders)
>       en Reale.IntegracionEasyVista.CustomTextEncoder.CustomTextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1
>   buffer, BufferManager bufferManager,
>   String contentType) en
>   E:\IntegracionEasyVista\CustomTextEncoder\CustomTextMessageEncoder.cs:línea
>   60
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream
>   stream, BufferManager bufferManager,
>   Int32 maxBufferSize, String
>   contentType)
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadChunkedBufferedMessage(Stream
>   inputStream)
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception&
>   requestException)
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation)
>
> en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

More info: part of WDSL of Service.php

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
 <definitions 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:si="http://soapinterop.org/xsd" 
xmlns:tns="http://192.168.110.50/WebService" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://192.168.110.50/WebService">
 <types>
 <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://192.168.110.50/WebService">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" /> 
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" /> 
  </xsd:schema>
  </types>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP service requires authentication but your client doesn't send any. Change your custom binding to support authentication. You can set authentication in httpTransport element:

```
<httpTranposrt authenticationScheme="..." />
```

Use Basic or Negotiate. Basic will require you to provide [client credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775.aspx) when communicating with the service. Negotiate will require that both service and client are in the same domain.

Comment: I try test but get errors.  Do I need add security mode in c ustomBinding ?? Do I need user and password of muy Domain User ?? I execute test with my Domain User.

Comment: I use scPro.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName, Password, but now I get error: Unrecognized message version